# Is there away to narrow down what I am selecting in my query using multiple joins and CTE with statements?

Tags: sql, join, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, common-table-expression

So I am working with a query that goes a little like this (see below) and I am trying to only pull out certain fields but I am having issues getting it to work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
WITH abc1 AS (
<some query that joins two tables together and lets say produces fields (a1,a2,a3)> ),

abc2 AS (
<some query that joins two tables together and lets say produces fields (b1,b2,b3)> ),

abc3 AS (
<some query that joins two tables together and lets say produces fields (c1,c2,c3)> )
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM abc1
```

This works and is the way I need it to be.

```
LEFT JOIN abc2
ON abc1.a1 = abc2.b1
```

Lets say that I only want to see abc2.b2 and not abc2.b1 & abc.b3 in the final results. How do I make this work?

```
LEFT JOIN abc3
ON abc1.a1 = abc3.c1
```

Let say that I only want to see abc3.c3 and not abc3.c1 or abc3.c2. Furthermore, if in the join between abc1 and abc3 produces a null, populate a 0, if there is a match, populate a 1. Something like this:

```
CASE WHEN abc3.c1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ACTIVE_IND
```

I tried this (post CTEs WITH statements) but it didn't work.

SELECT
      abc1.a1
      abc1.a2
      abc1.a3
      abc2.b2
      abc3.c3
    FROM (
      SELECT * FROM abc1

```
  LEFT JOIN abc2
  ON abc1.a1 = abc2.b1 

  LEFT JOIN abc3
  ON abc1.a1 = abc3.c1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want to see in the main query, instead of `*`.

For example:

```
WITH abc1 AS (
  ...
abc2 AS (
  ...
abc3 AS (
  ...
)
SELECT
  abc1.*,  -- all columns from the first CTE
  abc2.b2, -- only b2 from the second CTE
  abc3.c3  -- only c3 from the third CTE
FROM abc1 
LEFT JOIN abc2 ON abc1.a1 = abc2.b1
LEFT JOIN abc3 ON abc1.a1 = abc3.c1
```

Comment: Thanks! This methodology appears to work (although my query will take some time to finish - it is running!).